# Problems parsing text file

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
public class Data {

         public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
         String gender;
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("File Path"));
         String str;
         List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
         while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
         list.add(str);
         }

         String[] stringArr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
         System.out.println(list.size());
         Map<String, List<String>> genderNameList = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String line = list.get(i);
        String[] values = line.split("\\|");
        genderNameList.get(values[1]).add(values[1]);

    }

}}
```

Facing problem with the code. I have to read a file Vicky.txt which contains the data like

```
1. 123456|Mr|Peter|..........|19|||||
2. 556667|Ms|amith|..........|26|||||
3. 098765|Mr|kevinpeter|..........|24|||||
4. 675584|Mr|kapaul|..........|26|||||
5. 234906|Ms|zim|..........|24|||||
6. 123456|Ms|tom|..........|24|||||
```

Where the age is in the 28Th location in each row of a file. Here I have to read the file and collect all Age values in array and I have to display how many people are there with the age as 26 and how many are there with the age 24 and 19.

Here is the code that I did but its not working....

Comment: The most important compiler you write code for is other humans. Please format this code.

Comment: What is not working in the code? Are you getting compile errors? Is the code not doing what it's supposed to? What is your problem here?

Comment: Define "not working".  Stack Overflow is not a replacement for a debugger.  Explain the problem.  When you debug, where does the observed behavior differ from the expected behavior?  What are the values when that happens?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. To get good answers, include a descriptive title, post formatted code, and clearly identify what the problem is ("doesn't work" is not very specific)

Comment: If all you need to find out is `how many`, get the substring from the line, parse it and count the number of occurences. hint **frequency** :). Also, follow the comments above

Comment: The variables `gender` and `stringArr` are not used anywhere.

Comment: Don't bother reading the whole file into a list. Just process each line as you read it. Use a Map where the key is age and the value is the count.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your split works:

```
 String[] values = line.split("\\|");
```

What does this line do?

```
genderNameList.get(values[1]).add(values[1]);
```

It would seem like you need to process values[4]:

System.out.println("This line retrieves a value: " + values[4] + "for the 5th column.");

And if you want the 28th char,

```
line.charAt(27);
```

Comment: I have to read the text file line by line and display the data in 28th position of each line